# Show unique items with count of duplicate occurrences in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a below JSON:

```
[{"brand":"abc"},{"brand":"xyz"},{"brand":"abc"},{"brand":"abc"},{"brand":"por"},{"brand":"xyz"}]
```

Using `ng-repeat`, How can I display like -

```
Brand Occurances
abc      (3)
xyz      (2)
por      (1)
```

i.e. brand name (number of duplicate occurrences of same brand name)?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom function which will be returning the count from the existing array with the repeatvie values (occurances)

Along with the filter to show the unique values from the JSON:

```
$scope.getCount = function(i) {
    var iCount = iCount || 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.brands.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.brands[j].brand == i) {
        iCount++;
      }
    }
    return iCount;
  }
```

AND a filter will look like this:

```
app.filter('unique', function() {

  return function (arr, field) {
    var o = {}, i, l = arr.length, r = [];
    for(i=0; i<l;i+=1) {
      o[arr[i][field]] = arr[i];
    }
    for(i in o) {
      r.push(o[i]);
    }
    return r;
  };
})
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SymX0fsV6kbjG6ek8tRE?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

To get unique items from an array you could write a custom filter, in AngularJS filters are used to modify the data to be displayed to the user and in order to get the count of the duplicate items from an array you can write a function on the controller's scope and call it in the view.

Check the below code snippet on how to achieve it.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController)
  .filter('unique', unique);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [
    {
      "brand":"abc"
    },
    {
     "brand":"xyz"
    },
    {
     "brand":"abc"
    },
    {
     "brand":"abc"
    },
    {
     "brand":"por"
    },
    {
     "brand":"xyz"
    }
    ];
    
    vm.getBrandCount = getBrandCount;
    
    function getBrandCount(brand) {
      var count = 0;
      if (brand !== undefined && brand !== null && brand.length > 0) {
       for (var i = 0; i < vm.items.length; i++) {
          if (vm.items[i].brand === brand) {
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
      
      return count;
    }
  }
  
  function unique() {
    return function(array, key) {
      if (angular.isArray(array) && array.length > 0 && key !== undefined && key !== null && key.length > 0) {
        var arr = [], keys = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          if (keys.indexOf(array[i][key]) === -1) {
            keys.push(array[i][key]);
            arr.push(array[i]);
          }
        }
        
        return arr;
      }
      
      return array;
    }
  }
```

```css
.brandcount:before {
  content: '('
}

.brandcount:after {
  content: ')'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Brand</th>
          <th>Occurances</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | unique: 'brand'">
          <td>
            <span ng-bind="item.brand"></span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="brandcount" ng-bind="ctrl.getBrandCount(item.brand)"></span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first process your data before passing to `ng-repeat` like this:

```js
var app = angular.module("sa", []);

app.controller("FooController", function($scope) {

  var data = [{
    "brand": "abc"
  }, {
    "brand": "xyz"
  }, {
    "brand": "abc"
  }, {
    "brand": "abc"
  }, {
    "brand": "por"
  }, {
    "brand": "xyz"
  }];

  $scope.processedData = [];

  // Group the raw data based on the brand name and store the count
  function groupData() {

    angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
      // Check https://github.com/sagrawal14/angular-extras/blob/master/src/extras/array.js for this utility "find" method
      var existingBrand = $scope.processedData.find("brand", item.brand);

      if (!existingBrand) {
        existingBrand = item;
        existingBrand.count = 0;
        $scope.processedData.push(existingBrand);
      }

      existingBrand.count++;
    });
  }

  groupData();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/sagrawal14/angular-extras/master/src/extras/array.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sa" ng-controller="FooController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in processedData">
      <td>{{data.brand}}</td>
      <td>{{data.count}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br><br>Processed/grouped data: {{processedData | json}}
</div>
```